# Accesibilidad inconsciente en la propiedad del tipo DataSet

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

Estoy tratando de crear la capa de datos con Entity Framework Core en mi aplicación web .net core
pero me ha arrojado un error que no se lo que es.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0053  Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'DbSet' is less accessible than property 'DataContext.GuestResponses'  DataAccesLayer  C:\Users\Maf\source\repos\WebApplicationA\DataAccesLayer\DataContext.cs 12  Active

[image: Error CS0053 Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'DbSet<GuestResponse>' is less accessible than property 'DataContext.GuestResponses']

```
    class GuestResponse
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public bool? WillAttend { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código que tienes en tu clase GuestResponse.cs por favor?

Comment: listo :) ya edite el articulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca tu clase como pública, de tal manera tiene acceso desde tu `DataContext`

```
public class GuestResponse
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public bool? WillAttend { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: no me di cuenta muchas gracias de verdad :)

Comment: de nada mi estimada, bienvenida a la familia de StackOverflow en Español y bienvenida al mundo del desarrollo :D